# Getting Value of an Element in a Large List

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics, nodelist

I've researched this question, and it looks like most of the answers are concerned with retrieving the value of a first element in a nodelist, with a unique id or classname.

That said, I am using Adobe DTM to track an event on the sample code below. Just imagine a page full of li elements set up in this way.

```html
<li id="af3a2eb0-cfe9-11e5-b131-6fc0b40730a0" class="theater__active__3-QdV theater__theater__nmQh3 theaterTheater">
    <div class="theaterHead theater__header__2Skwj"> 
      <div class="theater__logo__2uovm">
        <img class="" src="image" alt="logo">
      </div>
      <div class="theaterInfo theater__theaterInfo__2dTbj">
        <h3 class="theater__theaterName__1Pwxo">Arclight</h3>
        <p class="theater__theaterAddress__16_be">10000 Wilshire Boulevard, Los Angeles, CA</p>
        <span class="theater__distance__30qj2 theater__theaterAddress__16_be">4.4mi</span>
      </div>
    <div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </li>
```

I am trying to get the value of the "h3" element when the click is on one of its parent divs.

So far I have this set up as a data element:

```js
var myNodelist = document.querySelector(".theater__theaterName__1Pwxo");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
    return myNodelist[i].value;
}
```

But it actually returns a blank value, and I'm not sure why!

Comment: Instead of bundling bits of data together and jamming them into the element class attribute you might want to use data- attributes and leave the class attribute for stuff like locating elements, styling elements, etc.

Comment: @James This is a really good idea, however I didn't build the page. Thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following expression in the click event to get the element text (make sure to append it to your prop or evar in the the event rule :

```
%this.@text%
```

**NOTE :** `this` will refer to the current clicked element.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey @Zakaria thanks, this actually got the innerText to show up. However, no matter which "tab" I click on, only the text from the first one shows up. Do I have to add some kind click condition?

Comment: Have you attached the click event elsewhere in your code ?

Comment: The click event, through Adobe DTM, is pointed at all the divs that have the classname "theaterHead theater__header__2Skwj" of which there are many. So, yes.

Comment: You should use `this` that point on the current element in your click event to get the appropriate text

Comment: Got it! The solution was %this.@text% the whole time.

Comment: This technique is nice and clean. Wish adobe made it more straight forward. @Leo_Taco, if this answer was the solution, please mark it as such.

Comment: Looks great. Though you should clarify that it needs to be appended to the prop or evar in the event rule.

Comment: Feel free @Leo_Taco to improve the post by editing...& congratulation you've earned the VOTE UP privilege, you could use it now it any post helps you...

Comment: Great thanks! I just made the edit and am really pumped about getting to VOTE UP